# Update multiple tables when using a join Max

Tags: mysql, magento, greatest-n-per-group

Here is the query I have to update pricing and updated_at field for a product on my Magento 2.0 mySQL database.

```
SET @etype = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product');
SET @price  = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'price' AND entity_type_id = @etype);

-- Admin store ID
SET @store = 0;


UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal d1

-- SELECT d1.row_id, d1.value AS 'Current', ip.sku, ip.price AS 'Updated', e.updated_at FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal d1
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(row_id) AS rowid, sku, updated_at FROM catalog_product_entity GROUP BY entity_id) e ON (d1.row_id = e.rowid)
  JOIN import_price ip ON e.sku = ip.sku
      AND d1.store_id = @store
      AND d1.attribute_id = @price
      
SET d1.value = ip.price, e.updated_at = NOW()
```

I am getting the error **The target table e of the UPDATE is not updatable**

I understand why I am getting the error, but I don't know how to fix.

If I remove the `, e.updated_at = NOW()` the query works fine.

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE prod23.catalog_product_entity (
  row_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Version Id',
  entity_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  created_in bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Update Id',
  updated_in bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 2147483647 COMMENT 'Next Update Id',
  attribute_set_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Attribute Set ID',
  type_id varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'simple' COMMENT 'Type ID',
  sku varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SKU',
  has_options smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Has Options',
  required_options smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Required Options',
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Creation Time',
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Update Time',
  PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
)
```

Comment: Add one more `catalog_product_entity` (joined properly, non-grouped) into the query and update the values in this copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your goal is to update only the rows in `catalog_product_entity` that have the greatest rowid for each `entity_id`, and leave other rows alone.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal d1
  JOIN catalog_product_entity e ON d1.row_id = e.row_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity e2 
      ON e2.entity_id = e.entity_id AND e2.row_id > e.row_id
  JOIN import_price ip ON e.sku = ip.sku
      AND d1.store_id = @store
      AND d1.attribute_id = @price
SET d1.value = ip.price, e.updated_at = NOW()
WHERE e2.row_id IS NULL;
```

The purpose of the join to `e2` is to find another row that has the same `entity_id` but a greater `row_id`. The condition `WHERE e2.row_id IS NULL` mean that we only want cases where there is no row `e2` with a greater `row_id` than the `id` of `e`. That will naturally mean that `e` is the row with the greatest `row_id` for its respective `entity_id`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. row_id is only unique field I have. I updated the original question with the structure of the catalog_product_entity table

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer with that in mind. Note I have not tested this, so I'll leave it to you to understand the principle and apply it to your case. Be sure to test it on some test data so you confirm it works the way you want it to, before you try it on your real tables.

Comment: are the e.rowid and e2.rowid fields on purpose? the field is row_id. Assuming its a typo I changed all rowid to row_id but got no results. Sorry if I am missing something obvious. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Fixed the typos.

Comment: Thank you. That was great!